# How to find variance given mean and sum of square numbers?

Tags: variance

A set of $20$ data values $\{x_1, x_2,\dots,x_{20}\}$ has $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{20} x_i^2 = 2872$ and $\mu=11$. Find the variance of the data set.

The answer given is 22.6

Comment: Remember that variance is $\frac{1}{20}\sum x^2 - \mu^2$.

Comment: What is your definition of variance? ($1/n$ or $1/(n-1)$?)

Comment: @user251257 There's only one definition. $1/(n-1)$ version is just an estimator from statistics (the one that makes bias = 0)

Comment: @Swistack variance is well-defined for random variables. But for samples you have to / should differentiate between population variance and sample variance.